# Runs a code I got written in angular js and gets an error message that I can't resolve

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, npm

When I try to run ng serve i get:
"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found".

I have already tried a few commands like :

> npm cache clean --force npm install -g @angular/cli
>
> ng update @angular/core --migrate-only --from=1.9.0 --allow-dirty --force
> 1>npm link typescript
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@
> npm uninstall -g @angular/core
> ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
> npm install -g @angular/core@latest
> npm install --save-dev @angular/core@latest

i try to delete node_modules and pakage-lock.json and then "npm i"

and still when i try; `ng serve`
i get:

```
"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."
```

Attaches here a picture of packeg jason:
[image: 1]
and pic of the terminal:
[image: terminal]

what can I do?
thanks

Comment: You added the picture of the terminal twice, and missed the package.json. Just to be on the safe side, you run the ``ng serve`` command in the same directory as your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Try to first check and install Angular Cli, then run following

> 1. npm install -g @angular/cli
> 2. ng new my-angular-project
> 3. cd my-angular-project
> 4. ng serve --open